# Display images from JS?

Tags: images, jquery, javascript

How can I get images from JavaScript? Code is given below:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $.vegas('slideshow', {
        backgrounds:[
            { src:'images/bg-slider/bg-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/bg-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/bg-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
        ]
    })();
});
```

I want to display images using `get_template_directory_uri()` or path of images.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how precisely your JS is output. If you are doing this inline from PHP you could just echo required data in place.

If it's just some arbitrary script, loaded as such, then the common practice in WP is to use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass data from PHP runtime to an enqueued script.

While by initial purpose (and name) the function was meant for localization, it handles arbitrary data just fine.

Comment: Will you make the code on wp_localize_script format. That the code is above. Can you please give me an example by using above code. Thanks.

Comment: The linked documentation has examples. If you have trouble making it work please update your question with what had you tried and how it fails.